# Extracting <a> tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am facing issue while extracting 'a' tags from https://www.symantec.com/index.jsp.

Following is the code, and its giving me empty set of the 'links'.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.symantec.com/index.jsp').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')
print(links)
```

For the other urls, the code is working, but its not working for this one. Is it because of index.jsp which is dynamic? What might be the resolution ?

I am using python 2.7.

Comment: You have a space between `https://www.symantec.com` and `/index.jsp`, perhaps removing that would fix your problem?

Comment: try using python requests to fetch the html...it works real nice.

Comment: @hd1 fixed the space, it was clearly a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @Rhea was the OP, alecxe, it may not have been a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the parser to `html5lib` or `lxml`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html5lib')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
```

It would require `html5lib` or `lxml` [to be installed:](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

```
pip install html5lib
pip install lxml
```

Proof:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> 
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.symantec.com/index.jsp').read()
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser').find_all("a"))
0
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(response, 'html5lib').find_all("a"))
187
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml').find_all("a"))
187
```

See also relevant parts of the documentation:

- [Specifying the parser to use](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use)
- [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

Comment: Why? What is different in other parsers

Comment: That question in my comment was intended to say "You need to explain this in your answer".

Comment: Also since you are only interested in part of the document you can create the  little unknown [`SoupStrainer`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) object and pass it as the `parse_only` argument to save time and memory.

Comment: @user3100115 yeah, good point, which can easily lead into premature optimization issues :)